# file_get_contents doesn't work with Steam API

Tags: php, file-get-contents, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to get Steam user's data in PHP with file_get_contents.

So I firstly built the URL and then passed it to file_get_contents. But when I do that, the page is loading during like 30 seconds and then I get a connection timed out.

Then I thought my URL wasn't good, so I echoed it and pasted it into my browser and it worked.

Eventually I thought my hosting service didn't activate it, because the exact same code worked in local. But no, file_get_contents successfully got http://www.google.com.

So how can I fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: I never really find the source of the problem. What I found out is that my server failed to reach Steam's one. So I used another server to get the data. I think as I was on a shared hosting, maybe the someone did something to Steam with this IP that got them banned.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to modify the [`default_socket_timeout`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) directive in your `php.ini` file, or by adding the following line in your script:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120); //sets timeout to 120 seconds
```

Comment: @tib20: did you restart the web-server after making the change? Once you've done that, you can check the value of `default_socket_timeout` using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: I didn't restart as it is a shared hosting, but added the ini_set function. And yes, it changed the value when I look into phpinfo(). But I do not think increasing timeout will help.